# Finding Absolute pressureThe

Tags: pressure

The pressure gauge on a steam condenser for a turbine indicates 26.2 in. Hg of vacuum. The barometer reading is 30.4 in. Hg. What is the absolute pressure (psia) in the condenser ?

according to my knowledge (not a lot),

The barometer reading is gauge pressure as most pressure measuring devices gives the gauge pressure .

According to the formula

Absolute pressure = gauge pressure + atmospheric pressure .

What is the atmospheric pressure according to this ? And why ? I'm not sure .

What does the 26.2 in. Hg of vacuum means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two corrections:

1. A barometer measures the atmospheric pressure, **relative to a vacuum at zero pressure**. Just look at the original barometer (and the source of the use of inches of Hg).  A 40 inch long tube is filled with mercury and inverted into a beaker of mercury.  The mercury falls until the pressure of the column of mercury equals the pressure of the atmosphere.
2. A pressure in **inches of vacuum** is measuring the gauge pressure; the pressure between the interior of the tank and the outside atmosphere.  The only quirk is that a **lower interior pressure** has a **positive** value. The pressure is that much **below** the reference atmospheric pressure.  So a tank with a pressure of 20 in Hg vacuum also has a pressure of -20 in Hg gauge pressure...